# How to retrieve data from multiple promise objects resolved through $.when in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, asynchronous, data-synchronization

Suppose we have only one promise object like below.

```
var myPromise = $.get(url1);
myPromise.done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

We are able to access the data from the promise object. Now suppose, we have multiple promise objects resolved via $.when

```
var multiplePromises = $.when($.get(url1),$.get(url2),$.get(url3));
multiplePromises.done(function(){

});
```

The above requirement has to be satisfied, that is, only if all the get requests completes, the done part should get executed. But how do I individually get the data response from each get to work with them in the $.when.done() method?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)? *"The arguments passed to the doneCallbacks provide the resolved values for each of the Deferreds, and matches the order the Deferreds were passed to jQuery.when()."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get them as arguments.

```js
function get(what) {
  return $.when(what)
}

$.when(get(1), get(2), get(3)).done(function(first, second, third) {
  console.log(first, second, third)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```